# Django foreign key: auto-lookup related object when the update record has the key value

Tags: django, django-orm

I have legacy code which had no foreign keys defined in the schema.
The raw data for the row includes the key value of the parent, naturally.
My first porting attempt to postgresql just updated the field with the raw value: I did not add foreign keys to Django's models.

Now I am trying to add foreign keys to make the schema more informative.

When I add a foreign key, django's update requires me to provide an instance of the parent object: I can no longer update by simply providing the key value. But this is onerous because now I need to include in my code knowledge of all the relations to go and fetch related objects, and have specific update calls per model. This seems crazy to me, at least starting from where I am, so I feel like I am really missing something.

Currently, the update code just pushes rows in blissful ignorance. The update code is generic for tables, which is easy when there are no relations.

Django's model data means that I can find the related object dynamically for any given model, and doing this means I can still keep very abstracted table update logic. So this is what I am thinking of doing. Or just doing raw SQL updates.

Does a solution to this already exist, even if I can't find it? I am expecting to be embarrassed.

The ValueError comes in django ORM code which knows exactly which model it expects and what the related field is: the missing step if to find the instance of related object.

db.models.fields.related_descriptors.py:
in this code, which throws the exception, value is supposed to be an instance of the parent model. Instead, value is the key value. This basically I think tells me how I can inspect the model to deal with this in advance, but I wonder if I am re-inventing the wheel.

```
 if value is not None and not isinstance(value, self.field.remote_field.model._meta.concrete_model):
            raise ValueError(
                'Cannot assign "%r": "%s.%s" must be a "%s" instance.' % (
                    value,
                    instance._meta.object_name,
                    self.field.name,
                    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
                )
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use _id suffix to set id value directly

For given model

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can set artist by id in following manner

```
Album.objects.create(artist_id=2)
```